# Read azure iot hub device data using built in endpoint

Tags: flutter, azure, dart, web-applications, azure-iot-hub

I am currently trying to read data sent from a device to an IoT Hub using built-in endpoints. I have used Python and successfully read the data. Now, I want to do this using the Dart language (Flutter). Is it possible? If so, are there any references on how to do it? Initially, I used the Python function EventHubConsumerClient.from_connection_string (endpoint connection string from Iothub -> built-in endpoints -> Eventhub compatible endpoint) to read data coming to the IoT Hub device from my ESP32. Now, I want to read the data from the ESP32 to the IoT Hub using Flutter (Dart language).

Comment: please share the details what you tried in above question

Comment: at first using python EventHubConsumerClient.from_connection_string(endpoint connection string (from iothub->built-in endpoints->Eventhub compatible endpoint))

Comment: using the above function I'm able read data coming to iothub device from my esp32.
Now I want to read the data esp32 to iothub using flutter (dart language).

Answer (score 0):

I followed this [DOC](https://medium.com/@lazydave/writing-to-azure-event-hub-using-flutter-ae59cf674fb8) to write to Azure Event Hub using Flutter, but there is no `azure_event_hub` package on [pub.dev](https://pub.dev/packages).

- Another method is to connect MQTT messages to [Event Hubs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/mqtt-routing-to-event-hubs-cli) and stream Flutter events with the Mosquitto MQTT [Broker](https://betterprogramming.pub/streaming-flutter-events-with-mosquitto-mqtt-broker-28998a3b81c2).

```dart
Future<int> connect() async {

client.logging(on: true);

client.keepAlivePeriod = 60;

client.onConnected = onConnected;

client.onDisconnected = onDisconnected;

client.onSubscribed = onSubscribed;

client.pongCallback = pong;

final connMessage =

MqttConnectMessage().startClean().withWillQos(MqttQos.atLeastOnce);

client.connectionMessage = connMessage;

try {

await client.connect();

} on NoConnectionException catch (e) {

print('MQTTClient::Client exception - $e');

client.disconnect();

} on SocketException catch (e) {

print('MQTTClient::Socket exception - $e');

client.disconnect();

}

return 0;

}
```

**Output:**

[image]

Alternative methods include Azure Event Hubs [Integration](https://www.rudderstack.com/integration/azure-event-hubs/) and Flutter SDK to Azure Event Hubs integration with [RudderStack](https://www.rudderstack.com/integration/azure-event-hubs/integrate-your-flutter-app-with-azure-event-hubs/).